# Is there a way to sample data from multiple columns using R

Tags: r

Say I have the following dataset (the dataset has more than 2000 observations). I would like to get the proportion (number) of males who are left-handed, pulse greater than or equal to 80 and clap with the there right hand.

How can I do this in R?

```
 X    Sex WrHnd NWHnd  WHnd    Fold Pulse    Clap Exer
1   1 Female  18.5  18.0 Right  R on L    92    Left Some
2   2   Male  19.5  20.5  Left  R on L   104    Left None
3   3   Male  18.0  13.3 Right  L on R    87 Neither None
4   4   Male  18.8  18.9 Right  R on L    NA Neither None
5   5   Male  20.0  20.0 Right Neither    35   Right Some
6   6 Female  18.0  17.7 Right  L on R    64   Right Some
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way that gives you the number at the end. I deliberately calculated for `Left` clap to produce an output for this small sample, but you can change it to `Right` in your big data.

```
library(dplyr)
df2 <- df %>% 
  filter(Sex == "Male" & WHnd == "Left" & Pulse >= 80 & Clap == "Left") %>% 
  count(.)

> df2
# A tibble: 1 x 1
      n
  <int>
1     1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dplyr` to first create a dataframe of all rows satisfying all your criteria

```r
library(dplyr)
select_Df <- df %>% filter(Sex == "Male" & WHnd == "Left" & Pulse >= 80 & Clap == "Right")
```

Then, you get the proportion of this group to the entire population by dividing the number of individuals contained in this new dataframe by the total number of individuals in the original dataframe:

```r
nrow(select_Df) / nrow(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `dplyr`

With your data.frame as `df`, you can calculate this proportion as follows:

`sum(df$Sex=='Male' & df$Whnd=='Left' & df$Pulse >= 80 & df$Clap=='Right') / nrow(df)`

because in R, the `sum(TRUE)` is `1`, the `sum(c(TRUE, TRUE))` is `2`, etc.